# .NET 4.5.2 conditions in a Wix bundle

Tags: wix

I'm working on a Wix project to learn more about Wix. I'm trying to configure my Wix bundle to detect and install .NET 4.5.2 but I'm a little confused. I've seen a lot of examples where the registry is checked but I wanted to know if I can do something like this:

```
<Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Redist" />

    <ExePackage Id="Netfx452"
                Cache="no"
                Compressed="yes"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Vital="yes"
                InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)Resources\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
                DetectCondition="NetFx452"
                InstallCondition="NOT NetFx452" />
    <MsiPackage Id="ShittyMsi" 
                SourceFile="$(var.MyInstaller.TargetDir)" 
                Name="$(var.MyInstaller.TargetFileName)" />
</Chain>
```

If I can't do this and I need to check the registry, how do I know what I need to be looking for in the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using `<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Redist" />` so you don't need to check the registry; the package group already takes care of checking the registry and setting the right attributes.

Comment: thanks for the information! I assume that means the example I pasted above would work since those variables should be set, is that correct?

Comment: It means you don't need the `ExePackage` at all.